# How to Maximize Outlook in background from Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to maximize outlook window in background, meaning without activating (focusing) it, from excel vba , How to ?

**Edit:** I found this solution works in addition to the below answer by user "Kostas K"

```
Dim aOutlook As Object

Set aOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
aOutlook.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Tested on Office 365.

```
Const olMaximized = 0

Dim ol As Object
Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

ol.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = olMaximized
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another answer:

```
Dim aOutlook As Object

Set aOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
aOutlook.ActiveWindow.WindowState = 2
```